# How to have the title at the top of the gantt chart?

Tags: pgfgantt

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for dummy text, remove in your own document

\usepackage{geometry} % to change margins
\usepackage{pdflscape} % provides the landscape environment
\usepackage{ragged2e} % provides \RaggedLeft

\begin{document}

% First option
\begin{ganttchart}[vgrid={draw=none,draw=none},%
        %today=15,%
        %today offset=.5,%
        %today label=Heute,%
        %progress=today,%
        x unit=0.3cm,
        y unit title=0.7cm,
        y unit chart=0.8cm,
        bar incomplete/.append style={fill=red},%
        progress label text=  {\quad\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0,verbatim]{#1}\%},
        milestone label font=\tiny,
        group label font=\tiny,
        title label font=\tiny,
        bar label node/.style={text width=3cm,align=right,font=\scriptsize\RaggedLeft,anchor=east},
        milestone label node/.style={text width=2cm,align=right,font=\scriptsize\RaggedLeft,anchor=east},
        group label node/.style={text width=3cm,align=right,font=\scriptsize\RaggedLeft,anchor=east}
        ]{1}{36}
\gantttitlecalendar*[compress calendar,time slot format=isodate]{2015-11-1}{2018-10-30}{year, month} \\
\gantttitlelist{1,...,36}{1}\\
\ganttgroup{Total Duration}{1}{36} \\
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Phase-1
\ganttgroup{Phase 1}{1}{12} \\
\ganttbar{Scope Reading}{1}{2} \\
\ganttlinkedbar{Literature Review}{2}{5} \ganttnewline
\ganttlinkedbar{Define Scope of Review}{5}{6} \ganttnewline
\ganttlinkedbar{Search for Relevant Literature}{6}{10} \ganttnewline
\ganttlinkedbar{Classify the Documents}{10}{12} \ganttnewline
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Phase-2
\ganttgroup{Phase 2}{12}{24} \\
\ganttlinkedbar{Solver Analysis $\&$ Formulation}{10}{15} \\
\ganttlinkedbar{Development of source code}{15}{16} \ganttnewline
\ganttlinkedbar{Purchase Equipment}{16}{18} \ganttnewline
\ganttlinkedbar{Design Experimental Procedure}{18}{20} \ganttnewline
\ganttlinkedbar{Run Experiments}{20}{21} \ganttnewline
\ganttlinkedbar{Analysis of Experimental Data}{21}{24} \ganttnewline
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Phase-3
\ganttgroup{Phase 3}{24}{36} \\
\ganttbar{Solving Validation and Conclusion}{24}{27} \\
\ganttlinkedbar{Publications $\&$ Workshops}{27}{30} \ganttnewline
\ganttlinkedbar{Defence of Study Work}{30}{33} \ganttnewline
\ganttlinkedbar{Thesis Writing}{33}{36} \ganttnewline
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{ganttchart}


% Second option
\newgeometry{vmargin=1cm}
\begin{landscape}
\thispagestyle{empty}\centering
\begin{ganttchart}[vgrid={draw=none,draw=none},%
        %today=15,%
        %today offset=.5,%
        %today label=Heute,%
        %progress=today,%
        y unit title=0.7cm,
        y unit chart=0.6cm,
        bar incomplete/.append style={fill=red},%
        progress label text=  {\quad\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0,verbatim]{#1}\%}%
        ]{1}{36}
\gantttitlecalendar*[compress calendar,time slot format=isodate]{2015-11-1}{2018-10-30}{year, month} \\
\gantttitlelist{1,...,36}{1}\\
\ganttgroup{Total Duration}{1}{36} \\
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Phase-1
\ganttgroup{Phase 1}{1}{12} \\
\ganttbar{Scope Reading}{1}{2} \\
\ganttlinkedbar{Literature Review}{2}{5} \ganttnewline
\ganttlinkedbar{Define Scope of Review}{5}{6} \ganttnewline
\ganttlinkedbar{Search for Relevant Literature}{6}{10} \ganttnewline
\ganttlinkedbar{Classify the Documents}{10}{12} \ganttnewline
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Phase-2
\ganttgroup{Phase 2}{12}{24} \\
\ganttlinkedbar{Solver Analysis $\&$ Formulation}{10}{15} \\
\ganttlinkedbar{Development of source code}{15}{16} \ganttnewline
\ganttlinkedbar{Purchase Equipment}{16}{18} \ganttnewline
\ganttlinkedbar{Design Experimental Procedure}{18}{20} \ganttnewline
\ganttlinkedbar{Run Experiments}{20}{21} \ganttnewline
\ganttlinkedbar{Analysis of Experimental Data}{21}{24} \ganttnewline
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Phase-3
\ganttgroup{Phase 3}{24}{36} \\
\ganttbar{Solving Validation and Conclusion}{24}{27} \\
\ganttlinkedbar{Publications $\&$ Workshops}{27}{30} \ganttnewline
\ganttlinkedbar{Defence of Study Work}{30}{33} \ganttnewline
\ganttlinkedbar{Thesis Writing}{33}{36} \ganttnewline
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{ganttchart}
\end{landscape}
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By adding `\gantttitle{Thesis Defence Timeline}{36} \\` before the rest of the chart adds a title to the entire chart as given. Other add-ons can be obtained from [gantt charts](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfgantt/pgfgantt.pdf).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for dummy text, remove in your own document

\usepackage{geometry} % to change margins
\usepackage{pdflscape} % provides the landscape environment
\usepackage{ragged2e} % provides \RaggedLeft

\begin{document}

% First option
\begin{ganttchart}[vgrid={draw=none,draw=none},%
        %today=15,%
        %today offset=.5,%
        %today label=Heute,%
        %progress=today,%
        x unit=0.3cm,
        y unit title=0.7cm,
        y unit chart=0.8cm,
        bar incomplete/.append style={fill=red},%
        progress label text=  {\quad\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0,verbatim]{#1}\%},
        milestone label font=\tiny,
        group label font=\tiny,
        title label font=\tiny,
        bar label node/.style={text width=3cm,align=right,font=\scriptsize\RaggedLeft,anchor=east},
        milestone label node/.style={text width=2cm,align=right,font=\scriptsize\RaggedLeft,anchor=east},
        group label node/.style={text width=3cm,align=right,font=\scriptsize\RaggedLeft,anchor=east}
        ]{1}{36}
\gantttitle{Thesis Defence Timeline}{36} \\
\gantttitlecalendar*[compress calendar,time slot format=isodate]{2015-11-1}{2018-10-30}{year, month} \\
\gantttitlelist{1,...,36}{1}\\
\ganttgroup{Total Duration}{1}{36} \\
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Phase-1
\ganttgroup{Phase 1}{1}{12} \\
\ganttbar{Scope Reading}{1}{2} \\
\ganttlinkedbar{Literature Review}{2}{5} \ganttnewline
\ganttlinkedbar{Define Scope of Review}{5}{6} \ganttnewline
\ganttlinkedbar{Search for Relevant Literature}{6}{10} \ganttnewline
\ganttlinkedbar{Classify the Documents}{10}{12} \ganttnewline
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Phase-2
\ganttgroup{Phase 2}{12}{24} \\
\ganttlinkedbar{Solver Analysis $\&$ Formulation}{10}{15} \\
\ganttlinkedbar{Development of source code}{15}{16} \ganttnewline
\ganttlinkedbar{Purchase Equipment}{16}{18} \ganttnewline
\ganttlinkedbar{Design Experimental Procedure}{18}{20} \ganttnewline
\ganttlinkedbar{Run Experiments}{20}{21} \ganttnewline
\ganttlinkedbar{Analysis of Experimental Data}{21}{24} \ganttnewline
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Phase-3
\ganttgroup{Phase 3}{24}{36} \\
\ganttbar{Solving Validation and Conclusion}{24}{27} \\
\ganttlinkedbar{Publications $\&$ Workshops}{27}{30} \ganttnewline
\ganttlinkedbar{Defence of Study Work}{30}{33} \ganttnewline
\ganttlinkedbar{Thesis Writing}{33}{36} \ganttnewline
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{ganttchart}


% Second option
\newgeometry{vmargin=1cm}
\begin{landscape}
\thispagestyle{empty}\centering
\begin{ganttchart}[vgrid={draw=none,draw=none},%
        %today=15,%
        %today offset=.5,%
        %today label=Heute,%
        %progress=today,%
        y unit title=0.7cm,
        y unit chart=0.6cm,
        bar incomplete/.append style={fill=red},%
        progress label text=  {\quad\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=0,verbatim]{#1}\%}%
        ]{1}{36}
\gantttitle{Thesis Defence Timeline}{36} \\
\gantttitlecalendar*[compress calendar,time slot format=isodate]{2015-11-1}{2018-10-30}{year, month} \\
\gantttitlelist{1,...,36}{1}\\
\ganttgroup{Total Duration}{1}{36} \\
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Phase-1
\ganttgroup{Phase 1}{1}{12} \\
\ganttbar{Scope Reading}{1}{2} \\
\ganttlinkedbar{Literature Review}{2}{5} \ganttnewline
\ganttlinkedbar{Define Scope of Review}{5}{6} \ganttnewline
\ganttlinkedbar{Search for Relevant Literature}{6}{10} \ganttnewline
\ganttlinkedbar{Classify the Documents}{10}{12} \ganttnewline
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Phase-2
\ganttgroup{Phase 2}{12}{24} \\
\ganttlinkedbar{Solver Analysis $\&$ Formulation}{10}{15} \\
\ganttlinkedbar{Development of source code}{15}{16} \ganttnewline
\ganttlinkedbar{Purchase Equipment}{16}{18} \ganttnewline
\ganttlinkedbar{Design Experimental Procedure}{18}{20} \ganttnewline
\ganttlinkedbar{Run Experiments}{20}{21} \ganttnewline
\ganttlinkedbar{Analysis of Experimental Data}{21}{24} \ganttnewline
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Phase-3
\ganttgroup{Phase 3}{24}{36} \\
\ganttbar{Solving Validation and Conclusion}{24}{27} \\
\ganttlinkedbar{Publications $\&$ Workshops}{27}{30} \ganttnewline
\ganttlinkedbar{Defence of Study Work}{30}{33} \ganttnewline
\ganttlinkedbar{Thesis Writing}{33}{36} \ganttnewline
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{ganttchart}
\end{landscape}
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is possible to conect the series bcz u find that there is some disconnecting like Analysis of Experimental Data and Solving Validation and Conclusion